# Help identify an unknown airborne object

Tags: aircraft-identification, night-flying

In the wee hours of the morning of last Saturday (July 30, 2016), while out stargazing, I saw something odd which I am unable to explain.

1. The object was traveling with a bearing of about 5-20° east of straight south.
2. The object flew nearly straight overhead, somewhat near the star Vega, sometime between 1:10-1:30AM local time (6:10-6:30AM GMT).  I was stargazing at the latitude and longitude 44.795614 N, 94.377516 W (https://goo.gl/maps/FB4yDsR8GYv).
3. The object was moving at a speed similar to an airplane.
4. The object's light blinked 3-4 times, but at a seemingly lower frequency than a typical airplane.  Also, while planes typically have a very short duration flash, this object had much longer flashes (1-2 seconds, probably), with the light being lit for about the same proportion of time as it was unlit.
5. I did not hear any propeller sounds, indicating that either that the object was relatively far away or that this was not a plane/helicopter.
6. The light also seemed brighter than a typical airplane's light, although I can't be entirely sure.  It was certainly brighter than every star in the sky.
7. After the 3-4 blinks, there were no more blinks (and this is on a wonderfully clear night; it's not possible that it was obscured by clouds, as I could still see the stars along the path it was flying)

From all this information, I am able to deduce that it was not a satellite, as satellites don't blink like this.  It is presumably not a typical commercial or private flight, even though there is a small airport roughly 4.5 miles north of where I was, because the lights stopped blinking, and that is presumably prohibited in nighttime flights.  I have not heard of any plane crashes nearby, which I expect I would have, had this been a plane that went down in flight.

Any ideas what I might have seen?

Comment: I apologize, but this is going to be almost impossible to answer. It could be anything from odd optical "tricks" to moon men from planet Florax. The lights could have "stopped blinking" because part of the aircraft got in the way of you seeing it. There just isn't a way to answer this factually.

Comment: Satellites don't blink (since they don't have light sources) but they can *appear* to blink as they move and catch the sun on solar panels etc from different angles. My guess would be an [Iridium flare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgCgTPSBEuY) or a similar flash from a smaller satellite.  If you are curious, install an app on your phone that will give you the time and location of the next Iridium flare in your area (or look it up online) then watch it.  Is it what you saw?

Comment: This is a good question but it is quite difficult to answer as there is no other evidence than you testimony. You should have capture some pictures/videos and make a description having in mind all what the comments and answer suggest so that your description could have been more specific (I know, it's too late now).

Comment: Check what flights passed at that time http://www.planeflighttracker.com/2014/02/flight-history-flightradar24.html

Comment: Yeah, I know that this is a very difficult one to answer.  I was just so curious that I wanted any help that I could get figuring out what it might have been.

@RonBeyer For what it's worth, it certainly wasn't an optical trick.  The only optics involved were my glasses, but there was no visible source of optical light that my glasses could have been reflecting so brightly.

Comment: I've edited to remove reference to 'UFO'. This technically means an unidentified flying object, but it's almost always taken as synonym for 'alien spacecraft'. Without that association you are more likely to get a sensible answer.

Comment: @Simon I wasn't aware that satellites can appear to blink.  I've seen satellites before, and the brightness of this object was comparable to the ISS.  I don't know if there are any satellites that can be about as bright as the ISS (I don't think so, but I could be wrong), but the ISS was certainly not in the same part of the sky at the time, so it was not the ISS.

Comment: @ManuH I immediately turned my camera to the object and started exposing the sensor, but that was right when the lights stopped blinking :/

Comment: @DJClayworth I thought about that, but I figured that mentioning "UFO" would pique people's interest, and that given the that the StackExhange population is relatively well-educated, I figured the majority wouldn't jump to thinking aliens :P

Comment: @BenSandeen You don't need to be using an optical device to get an optical illusion. The atmosphere itself can play wonderful tricks. I've seen highway lights high in the sky reflecting off of ice crystals at high altitudes.

Comment: @RonBeyer Really?!  That's surprising.  Although I'm pretty sure this was some flying object, given that it was moving in a consistent direction with constant speed, while I was standing still.  Also, since the blinking light was so regular, that'd seem to stand against a hypothesis of atmospheric effects.  I'd love to see something like what you mention, though!

Comment: @ViktorMellgren I checked out that nifty site, and from 12:30AM to 2:00AM, the only aircraft that crossed overhead in anything remotely near the correct direction was a FedEx plane, FX137, sometime around 12:40-12:45AM.

However, it did seem like the object I saw was traveling slightly west of straight south, while this FedEx plane was traveling slightly east of straight south.  I am not entirely sure about the direction the object was traveling in, though, and I could be mistaken.  But I'm still quite skeptical.

Comment: I said Iridium, not ISS.  Iridium flares are at least as bright as the ISS, indeed most of them have the lowest magnitude of any object in the sky for a second or two.  Several other types of satellite also flare but with magnitudes quite a bit larger.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that the ISS was the brightest satellite.  When you mentioned Iridium flares, I just assumed that they were some sort of meteor shower-related thing, because iridium is an element.  I didn't realize there was also a constellation of satellites that share the same name!

Comment: Your description reminds me of seeing military aircraft practicing in-flight refueling. The blinking lights you saw might be called rendezvous lights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best guess is **you saw a high altitude aircraft flashing its landing lights.**

Landing lights serve a number of purposes. Besides illuminating the landing surface, they can also be used to signal other planes as they are so bright. To experience how bright they are, stand near the approach or departure path of a busy airport at night.

The reason for the pilots flashing the landing lights in your scenario is unknown. It could be signaling another plane on a potential collision course, or just a way of saying hello to other traffic (hey, cruising a commercial airliner is kinda bored, huh?).

Without any visual reference, judging distances on a nighty sky can be tricky. Flashing a light is a convenient way of saying "hey I'm here!" to other planes. It is likely that your judgment of the flying object's distance was also impaired by the night environment. The only reliable observation I would pick is that you did not hear any sound, which suggests the object was very far away.

Comment: But is it permitted for an aircraft to fly without any lights whatsoever?

Comment: @BenSandeen No it is not permissible for aircraft to do fly without lights on.

Comment: @BenSandeen it is possible that the navigation lights were very dim at your distance, or obscured by part of the airframe (after all they're not designed to be observed at this angle)

Comment: @kevin True, but I doubt that it would be blinking with perfect regularity, if that was the case.

Comment: @kevin Oh wait, I see what you mean; you were saying that they would never have been visible at all, and that blinking lights I saw were just the landing lights.  That seems plausible enough